# Why warning message is not displayed when running query in query tool like sql* plus?

Tags: database, oracle, sqlplus

I got this in production and not able to reproduce the same warning message in testing platform.

The warning message I got is like

```
 ORA-24347: Warning of a NULL column in an aggregate function
```

Consider I am passing null column to aggregate function.

When I run the same query in query tool, I am not getting any warning message.

What is the rationale behind this?

Comment: can you share the query you are using ?

Comment: SELECT MAX(NULL) FROM DUAL; I am expecting this query should display warning message and I am not getting it.

Comment: I didnt understand so this query select max null would give you error

Comment: @Moudiz Do you have access to oracle bug database. Many people have complained this and still we don't have idea like whether this is fixed by oracle. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40926515/ora-24347-warning-of-a-null-column-in-an-aggregate-function-with-php5-3-3

Comment: yes i noticed that is a bug (in 9i and 10g), try to talk with the oracle support about it. what oracle version do you have ?

Comment: @Moudiz No I expect this query should give a warning like ORA-24347: Warning of a NULL column in an aggregate function

Comment: well it shouldnt i run it locally here and it return null,

Comment: Oracle 12.2.0 Currently  I don't have access to oracle support. Do you guys have it?

Comment: well oracle support only support databases that have licences anyway, check if its data issue , if it is a bug then i cannot help you.

Comment: @Moudiz If you have access to bug database, can you check when it is fixed and whether it is fixed for oracle 12.2?

Comment: ORA-24347 has been a side-effect of several different bugs over various versions of Oracle. So what you're seeing depends on some peculiarity of your Production environment. Obviously we can't remotely diagnose your system. If your organisation doesn't pay for an Oracle Support contract you'll have to figure it out for yourself. Start by determining what is different between your Test and Production environments. Alternatively, just re-write the failing code to bulletproof it against null values: Oracle has plenty of functions to handle nulls: NVL, NVL2, CASE, COALESCE, etc

Comment: @APC I will try to add NVL. But many posts says that they are facing issue even after adding null. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40926515/ora-24347-warning-of-a-null-column-in-an-aggregate-function-with-php5-3-3. See comments section of this post.

Comment: Alas, this problem is dependent on **your code** in **your production environment**. So things might work or they might not work.

Comment: @APC Finally we are able to connect with ORACLE support team. It is confirmed as bug by oracle team.

Answer (score 1):

We are able to connect with oracle team. It is oracle bug and it is accepted by that team.

Comment: Glad you got some traction with it.